# How to get the device token of a mac?

Tags: macos, safari, notifications, pushwoosh

I am using the PushWoosh solution to present and send the notifications from my webpage to the mac users.

I would like to set my computer also as a test device where I could check and test my notifications.

To do this, the PushWoosh wants from me the device token of my mac. How and where can I get it?

Here you can see the screen of PushWoosh:
[image]

Comment: does PushWoosh allow a device type of MacOS?  Your screenshot shows "iOS".

Comment: Yes, of course Pushwoosh allow MacOS X devices, you can choose it from device type. What device type you need webiste, mac? I think you integrate safari pushes then you need safari pushtoken here. And choose Safari device type of test device. You can get it when integrate javascript from Pushwoosh guide on you site from https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/safari/safari-website-notifications/ in console.log you will see pushtoken of you current device

Answer (score 0):

This paragraph in the ["Notification Programming Guide for Websites" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW8) seems potentially useful:

> To check the permission level a user has set for your website, call
>   `window.safari.pushNotification.permission()` with your Website Push
>   ID as an argument. This synchronous call returns a permission object
>   for the given identifier by looking in the user’s preferences. This
>   function does not contact your server.

One of the items passed back in the permission object structure is `deviceToken`, which appears to be what you are looking for.